# How to take registry backup of current network properties

Tags: windows, registry

I want to take back up of registry of the current network settings like IP,Subnet,DNS and all that stuff, in windows xp. How can i do that? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows XP clients and higher, the `netsh` command has access to all your nitty-gritty networking configuration. Rather than fool with Registry stuff (which may be incomplete, since the network config is in many places), you might do better by using the `netsh dump > ipsettings.bak` command to save a configuration script. If you need to restore the settings due to bad changes, simply run `netsh exec ipsettings.bak` and you're back in business.

Answer (score 1):

Either use the [FreeIPSwitcher](http://www.eusing.com/ipswitch/free_ip_switcher.htm) or (using your chosen language - not specified) backup HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces